# Using cast or convert to convert negative int values to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, casting

I have some negative integer values which are an offset from the default 1-1-1900 date. I have to get the datetime values from these. How can I do this.

Example:

If I do:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, 53691) as Calc

OR

SELECT cast(53691 as datetime)
```

I get: `2047-01-01 00:00:00.000`

What I need is that If I do:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, -53691) as Calc

OR

SELECT cast(-53691 as datetime)
```

I should get something like:

```
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-53690 would be 1753-01-01. -53691 takes you out of the range of the [datetime data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) (which doesn't support dates before 1753). Casting -53690 works as your other examples do.